# How to get a value from attribute?

Tags: c#, attributes

Let's have a attribute with an int paramter in the ctor

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class EntityBindingAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int I { get; set; }

    public EntityBindingAttribute(int i)
    {
        I = i;
    }
}
```

How can I access this value using code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Get all the attributes for the class
Attribute[] _attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NameOfYourClass));

// Get a value from the first attribute of the given type assuming there is one
int _i = _attributes.Where(_a => _a is EntityBindingAttribute).First().I;
```

Comment: This works as long as the attribute class has that attribute.

Comment: Yes, mentioned in the comments 'assuming there is one'. It's easy to change the code to use FirstOrDefault and then check for a null reference before accessing the property I. Omitted that in the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

You would use the [Attribute.GetCustomAttributes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.getcustomattributes.aspx), with the overload that matches the object where the attribute has been set.

For example if the attribute is set on a method, something like:

```
MethodInfo mInfo = myClass.GetMethod("MyMethod");
foreach(Attribute attr in Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(mInfo))
{
   if (attr.GetType() == typeof(EntityBindingAttribute))
   {
     int i = ((EntityBindingAttribute)attr).I);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which method is for getting attributes from a class ?

Comment: System.Type is actually a System.Reflection.MemberInfo so it's the same method, like this Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyClass))